# Laravel model relation validation in request

Tags: php, validation, laravel

I find myself doing stuff like this in my controllers whenever I pass in two or more parameters that are related to eachother.

For example I have this route:

```
Route::patch('user/{user}/post/{post}', 'PostController@update');
```

Which leads to something like this:

```
public function update(User $user, Post $post, PostRequest $request)
{
  if($user->id != $post->user_id) {
    // return with error
  }

  // continue
}
```

Is there a way to put the relation validation in the `PostRequest`-class?

Comment: You've to create a custom relation based validation

Comment: Check out this post https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-middleware-owner go to the response by  martinbean

Comment: I suggest you have a look at authorization (https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authorization) section in laravel docs

Comment: Thanks @Brett, that works fine. Also I now found out when to put something else than just `return true` in the authorize() method. @geoandri, thanks, it also mentions the FormRequests.

Answer (score 0):

Yes You Could redirect back with error. Try this:

```
if($user->id != $post->user_id) {
    return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Something went wrong.');
}
```